# I am trying to understand the code of an Assembly exercise, so that I can solve it myself with different values after

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I am in university and I have an exam in Assembly, the exercises are generally identical on each exam, except for the values that are changed. I would like to understand how to understand the following code and how to solve it myself after with different values. Thank you for any attempt to help.

The exercise asks what the order is of the output messages after the code is executed.

I have tried to understand what each register and command does, but to not avail, because of the complexity of the exercise. I know the basics of an Assembly program, but the way the values are manipulated in this exercise dulls me.

iins sets a priority for a task irun runs that task until it meets a wait or exit isetf and setf set a flag (F1-F4) to 1 and clef sets it to 0 wait means that the instructions will be continued after the flag becomes 0 (with clef), after this the task with the highest priority continues after the wait

```
T0:    extrn          afis
       iins           1, T1, STACK1
       irun           1
       isetf          F1
       setf           F4
       exit
T1:    isetf           F3
       iins           3, T2, STACK2
       irun           3
       wait           F4
       mov            si, OFFSET mes1a
       call           afis
       wait           F3
       exit
T2:    iins           2, T3, STACK3
       irun           2
       mov            si, OFFSET mes1b
       call           afis
       wait           F4
       mov            si, OFFSET mes2b
       call           afis
       clef           F3
       exit
T3:    mov            si, OFFSET mes1c
       call           afis
       clef           F4
       mov            si, OFFSET mes2c
       call           afis
       clef           F1
       exit
mes1a  db CR, LF, "TaskT1:mes1a....",$
mes2a  db CR, LF, "TaskT1:mes1a....",$
mes1b  db CR, LF, "TaskT2:mes1b....",$
mes2b  db CR, LE, "TaskT2:mes2b....",$
mes1c  db CR, LE, "TaskT3:mes1c....",$
mes2c  db CR, LE, "TaskT3:mes2c....",$
       F1             equ              30
       F3             equ              32
       F3             equ              34
       END.
```

What I figured out so far was:
T1 - 1st priority, T2 - 3rd priority, T3 - 2nd priority

T0 sets the flags F1 and F4 to 1 goes into T1 which runs and waits for F4 to become 0, goes into T2 which outputs the message found at mes1b:

```
"TaskT2:mes1b...."
```

then it waits for F4 as well, goes into T3 which outputs mes1c so we will have:

```
"TaskT2:mes1b....
 TaskT3:mes1c...."
```

F4 becomes 0, T1 continues because it has the highest priority and outputs mes1a:

```
 TaskT3:mes1c....
 TaskT1:mes1a...."
```

then it waits for F3 and goes into T3 because T3 has a bigger priority than T2, T3 outputs mes2c

```
 TaskT3:mes1c....
 TaskT1:mes1a....
 TaskT3:mes2c...."
```

then T3 changes the value of flag F1 to 0 and this is where I am stuck. I think I am missing a wait F1 somewhere.

Comment: What architecture are you programming for?

Comment: assembly i8086.

Comment: This sounds like you're asking someone else to do your homework here. You haven't even elaborated on what part you are stuck on. What have you figured out so far? Why hasn't that lead you to the answer you were looking for?

Comment: This doesn't look like 8086 assembly to me.  You can see the 8086 instruction set [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#Original_8086/8088_instructions) and it contains nothing like `iins`, `irun`, `isetf`, `clef`, etc.  Are they macros perhaps?  We'd need to see the definitions of those macros to make any sense of this.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers It's not my homework, just trying to figure it out so that I can do it myself. 
I realized after posting, 

iins sets a priority for a task
irun runs that task until it meets a wait or exit 
isetf and setf set a flag (F1-F4) to 1 and clef sets it to 0
wait means that the instructions will be continued after the flag becomes 0 (with clef), after this the task with the highest priority continues after the wait

Comment: I will update in the OP what my results so far are..

Comment: @NateEldredge updated in the OP what the macros do. I apologize for the inconvenience, did not know they were macros.

Comment: Hmm, so this is something very different than an actual 8086, which has no concept of "tasks" or multitasking.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see, according to the "syllabus" it is supposed to be an 8086, I guess the professor took his liberties with macros. I am missing a crucial part of the code I think so I may have wasted everyone's time, since there is a clef F1 at T3 there is supposed to be a wait F1 somewhere.